# C# await in UI thread

Tags: c#

According to *Microsoft Visual C# Step by Step 9th edition*:

> The await operator indicates that a method should be run by separate task,
> and the calling code is suspended until the method call completes.
> The thread used by the calling code is released and reused.
> This is important if thread is the user interface thread, as it enables the user interface to remain responsive.

Suppose I have a method that is IO bound and frees up the CPU:

```
private async Task DoLongRunningIO()
{
    ...
}
```

Does the above paragraph mean that running

```
await DoLongRunningIO();
message.Text = "Done";
```

in the UI thread will still keep the UI responsive since the UI thread is released? (as opposed to `DoLongRunningIO().Wait()`, which would block the UI thread)

If the answer is yes, I assume it wouldn't be true if the long running task was CPU intensive instead, since the UI thread is still consumed in that case?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a question for here. This sounds like something that you can easily set up tests for and discover for yourself.

Comment: @Enigmativity I disagree - this is *not* easy to test.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica - Why not?

Comment: @Enigmativity What do you suggest that I do to simulate long running IO?. Sleep() is what I normally use to simulate any sort of delay, but in this case I think that's off the table since I actually don't want to suspend the thread.

Comment: If you use Microsoft's Reactive Framework you can call `int result = await Observable.Return(42);` (this is a trivial example). That code is awaited but there is no task in that code. Your book is a bit bogus.

Comment: @youn - Why not use `Thread.Sleep`? It's perfectly fine inside a `Task.Run(() => ... )`.

Comment: Since my understanding was that await schedules the task in the calling thread. If the calling thread was UI, by this logic it will suspend the UI thread when I actually want to test its responsiveness. My understanding is being debated. I may very well have to set up a test to find out myself.

Comment: @youn - You do seem to have a wrong impression of `await` and I think it's the book's fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the above paragraph mean that running
>
> ```cs
> await DoLongRunningIO();
> message.Text = "Done";
> ```
>
> in the UI thread will still keep the UI responsive since the UI thread is released?

Yes.

> If the answer is yes, I assume it wouldn't be true if the long running task was CPU intensive instead, since the UI thread is still consumed in that case?

No, your assumption is incorrect. A "thread" and the "CPU" are not the same thing. Even if your machine has only a single CPU, there can be one CPU-intensive thread running, and the UI thread running, and the OS will share the CPU between them. You may find a slightly degradation in responsiveness, but the UI thread will still be able to run.

If you have more than one CPU core, as is the case with pretty much all modern hardware, then as long as the two threads don't interact, the UI thread will be able to run unimpeded, even if there is also a CPU-intensive thread running.

Note that this all assumes that the `DoLongRunningIO()` method was written correctly, i.e. does in fact reflect an operation that is handled asynchronously. For a CPU-intensive task, this would generally include a call to `Task.Run()` to execute the operation, though there are of course other mechanisms that could be used instead.

If that method is written incorrectly, then all bets are off. You didn't provide any details about that method, so it's impossible to say whether that's the case in your scenario.

**Aside:**

For what it's worth, I take issue with the phrasing *"The await operator indicates that a method should be run by separate task"* that you quoted from the book. The `await` operator says *nothing* about *how* a method or operation should be run/called/carried out/etc. The only thing that `await` does is indicate a point in the *current* method where, given an awaitable object (typically a `Task`), the method should return to the caller if the object is not in the completed state. It is up to whatever expression generates the awaitable object to handle *how* that task is created and whether it is done in a separate thread or otherwise in an asynchronous manner.

Comment: I thought the await keyword specifically schedules the task on the thread of the calling method (i.e. it does not spawn a new thread). Hence my comment about UI thread being consumed.

From the same chapter in the book: _When the C# compiler encounters the await operator in an async method, it effectively reformats the operand that follows this operator as a task that runs on the same thread as the async method._

Comment: _"I thought the await keyword specifically schedules the task on the thread of the calling method"_ -- no, that is a completely incorrect understanding of the `await` operator. See my edit above; the `await` operator doesn't have _anything_ to do with scheduling the awaitable work. It _only_ governs the mechanism by which the current method deals with waiting for that awaitable work (i.e. in particular, by setting up the compiler-generated state machine so that the method can be resumed at the appropriate place, and then returning to the caller).

Comment: I'm really not liking the book you are quoting. If it really says _"it effectively reformats the operand that follows this operator as a task that runs on the same thread as the async method"_, then it is not a book that should be used. The `await` operator doesn't "reformat" anything, and it certainly doesn't affect where the _operand_ of the operator (i.e. the awaitable expression) is executed. It _can_ affect where the code in the method _following the statement containing the `await`_ is executed, e.g. by allowing the method to return to the original thread, as in a UI thread.

Comment: Are you saying that C# can schedule an awaited task on another thread?

Comment: _"Are you saying that C# can schedule an awaited task on another thread?"_ -- I'm saying that awaiting a task has nothing to do with where that task is scheduled. By the time the code gets around to awaiting it, the scheduling has already been done. The awaiting is completely irrelevant as far as the scheduling goes.

Comment: Await has nothing to do with scheduling of tasks.  It's up to the task itself how it gets scheduled.  Await simply specifies how *this* function will be resumed when the task completed.

Comment: @youn: That's not going to happen if you are executing in a UI environment like WinForms or WPF. However, in a non-UI environment, that can happen, in fact ASP.NET Core makes no promises in this regard (as far as I know)